How to update a Rune from within a triggered event?
I have a global rune store that keeps track of document properties like so:
export class DocState {
    #properties = $state(new Map());

    constructor() {}

    add(prop: string, value: string) {
        this.#properties.set(prop, value);
    }

    set(props: Word.DocumentProperties, controls: Word.ContentControl[]) {
        const _P = props as any;
        for (const p of coreProperties) {
            if (_P[p]) {
                this.#properties.set(p, _P[p]);
            }
        }
        for (const c of controls) {
            if (c.title) {
                this.#properties.set(c.title, c.text);
            }
        }
        return this.#properties;
    }

    get(prop: string) {
        return this.#properties.get(prop);
    }

    getAll() {
        return this.#properties;
    }
}

const DOCPROP_KEY = Symbol('DOCPROPERTIES');
export function setDocState() {
    return setContext(DOCPROP_KEY, new DocState());
}
export function getDocState() {
    return getContext<ReturnType<typeof setDocState>>(DOCPROP_KEY);
}

This works fine when inside a component. But it feels very weird to have a service get the properties and controls from a document, give them to a component and then have the component do the state changes. And worse still, I have an event that gets triggered when a user inserts a new content control to the document or changes an existing one but how can I update the state with the new control? When I have the service or event handler try to access the store, I get an error it's outside the livecycle hook.
For example, if I define a component and run
const _D = getDocState()
const { properties } = _D.getAll()

I can iterate over the items just fine with
{#each [...properties] as [prop, value]}
 {prop} {value}
{/each}

But all content controls in the document have an event handler:
  ...
  contentControls.forEach(async (control) => {
    control.onDataChanged.add(contentControlDataChanged);
  }
  ...

So now when a user changes a contentcontrol, the event is triggered. I need to update the store accordingly but I can't access it because of the lifecycle error because the contentControlDataChanged function is in a service.ts file.
What would be the correct way to handle this?

I don't really understand the problem at hand. Maybe a concrete usage example/showing what you would like to achieve with this would help.

roger; I added an example to the question.
